# Como contar itens repetidos de forma respectiva com javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Exemplo:

```
const cores = [{id: 1, cor: 'azul'}, {id: 2, cor: 'azul'}, {id: 3, cor: 'azul'}, {id:4, cor: 'verde'}, {id: 5, cor: 'verde'}, {id: 6, cor: 'azul'}, {id: 7, cor: 'verde'}, {id: 8, cor: 'marrom'}, {id: 9, cor: 'marrom'}];
```

Objeto final a ser retornado ao contar os itens repetidos de forma respectiva:

```
const objeto = [{cor: 'azul', total: 3}, {cor: 'verde', total: 2}, {cor: 'Azul', total: 1}, {cor: verde, total: 1}, {cor: 'marrom', total: 2}];
```

Quebrei bastante a cabeça com map e filter e este foi o resultado:

```
cores.map(item => item.cor).map(value => { if(value !== cor) { cor = value; count = 1; return value; } else { count = ++count; cor = value; } return count; });

(9) ["azul", 2, 3, "verde", 2, "azul", "verde", "marrom", 2]
```

Percebam que eu consegui o valor e o resultado final dos que possuem quantidades maiores que 1. Após a cor azul, o numero 2 e 3 são as contagens feitas pelo map acima e 3 e o total de azul da primeira ocorrência. Após isto o verde que possui 2 ocorrências, depois o azul e o verde que tem apenas 1 ocorrência mais não consegui que eles retornassem o valor inteiro 1, depois o marrom que possui 2 ocorrências repetidas.  Após isto tentei refazer de outras maneiras mais apenas códigos falhos.

Comment: Quais códigos você tentou fazer? Edite a sua pergunta para que possamos saber melhor como lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não use `map`, ele não serve para isso.

`map` serve para transformar os elementos do array em outra coisa. Por exemplo:

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(x.map(n => n * 2)); // imprime o dobro dos números
```

No exemplo acima eu transformei cada número no seu dobro. `map` serve para isso, e o detalhe importante é que o resultado tem o mesmo número de elementos do array original (para cada elemento, há um resultado correspondente).

Mas no seu caso, isso não é necessariamente verdade. O seu array original tem 9 elementos, e o resultado pode ter menos, então `map` não é o mais adequado (`filter` também não faz sentido, pois ele serve para escolher elementos do array baseado em algum critério, mas você não quer escolher nenhum, quer apenas somar as quantidades de elementos consecutivos com a mesma cor).

Sendo assim, é mais fácil fazer um `for` simples e verificar se o elemento é igual ao próximo (se for, incrementa a contagem, senão adiciona o total e começa a contagem de novo):

```js
const cores = [{id: 1, cor: 'azul'}, {id: 2, cor: 'azul'}, {id: 3, cor: 'azul'}, {id:4, cor: 'verde'}, {id: 5, cor: 'verde'},
 {id: 6, cor: 'azul'}, {id: 7, cor: 'verde'}, {id: 8, cor: 'marrom'}, {id: 9, cor: 'marrom'}];

let cont = [];
let total = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < cores.length; i++) {
    if (i < cores.length - 1 && cores[i].cor == cores[i + 1].cor) {
        total++;
    } else {
        cont.push({ cor: cores[i].cor, total: total });
        total = 1;
    }
}
console.log(cont);
```